# findOneAndUpdate in mongodb return only updated values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have to create a logbook for my application (MEAN-Stack). I need to know, which user changed fields inside the customer document and when he did it. Knowing which user it was and when is no problem. But i want my logbook to be as "clean" as possible so i would like to only write down changed values.

Lets take this example:

```
customer : {
    name: Customer Ltd.
    address: FooStreet 11
    zip: 21412
    country: Germany
}
```

the user now changes the zip with this function (`req.body.customer` includes whole customer document, not only changed fields)

```
const customer = await Customer.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.id }, { $set: req.body.customer }, { new: true });
```

is there any possibility to get changed fields from `findOneAndUpdate()` or maybe there is a better approach to solve what i want?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findOneAndUpdate` takes a `returnNewDocument` option that returns the updated document rather than the original document -- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/